# Why won't this RegEx-Pattern work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to create a pattern for this string: `(abcde ...` and it looks like this:

```
\b(?=[(])[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\b
```

I want `abcde` to be selected.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Lookaheads have zero-length. You are looking at the word boundary, checking that an opening brace follows and then do not allow braces to follow.

Comment: How is it not working? What results are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for *look behind* (`?<=`) which Javascript Regex doesn't support, try capture the pattern you need and extract it with `match`:

```js
console.log(
  "(abcde...".match(/\((\w+)\b/)[1]
)
```

Comment: It's a lookahead in the question, not a lookbehind. Secondly, javascript does know lookaheads. See: https://regex101.com/r/ar5i1N/1

Comment: @mlambrichs Yeah. What OP has is *lookahead*. But it seems he is looking for *look behind*.

Comment: Another solution is to reverse the string then use a look ahead.

Comment: This reversing idea is only working when you only need one type of a lookaround and makes sense when overlapping matches are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.

- the lookahead doesn't consume characters
- boundary '\b' matches '('

source `(abcde ...`
Now check the following regexes:

```
\b(?=[(])([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\b      # doesn't match

\b(?=[(]).([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\b     # doesn't match
```

and finally:

```
(?=[(]).([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\b        # matches
```

So, logically, in the first regex, the \b matches the '('. After that the lookahead fails brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

brace `(`  already acts as word boundary, remove `\b` at start of the pattern:

```
\([a-zA-Z_0-9]+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/MZhqSL/2